# Why: error: array subscript is above array bounds

Tags: arrays, gcc, gcc-warning

I've looked at other entries in stack overflow, but they are legitimately "above" the bounds.

In my code, I am winding my way through a nested series of structures:

```
static inline void * get_resp_ptr(U32 blade_ix, U32 q_id)
{
    per_blade_data *  bd  = bfr_blade_data + blade_ix;
    bfr_pendcmd_q_t * pcq = bd->bfrpb_ques + q_id;
    response_t *      res = pcq->bfrpq_resp;
    return (void *)(res + pcq->bfrpq_resp_rdix);
}
```

"bfrpq_resp" is a pointer to type response_t.  The last two lines of this function *both* get the error message.  Beats heck out of me....Any guesses about what the compiler is trying to say?  I'm tempted to cast into uintptr_t and just use arithmetic. :(

Edit:  that didn't work.  The assignment of pcq->bfrpq_resp to a uintptr_t resulted in the same error message.  Merely referencing the field yields the result.  I think GCC needs a different error message here.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45978 , if your `gcc` version is below `4.7.0`

Comment: Conceivably. I am a bit dubious because I do not index bfrpq_resp on that line.  Not until the return statement.  Then again, I am using:  mips64-octeon-linux-gnu-gcc (Cavium Inc. Version: 2_3_0 build 116) 4.3.3, perhaps too old for that bug ;).  Another possibility is some confusion about bfrpb_ques + q_id.  That is an array of 9 elements where q_id is always passed as a constant 0 thru 8.  I'll run that down.....

Answer (score 0):

GCC bug triggered by my own coding.  GCC points to that line, but the issue is the previous line caused by stumbled fingers.  Thank you.  I won't file a GCC bug because 4.3.3 is a bit long in the tooth.